# Is there a tool for signing all jars in a folder and subfolders?

Tags: java

Is there a tool for signing all jars in a folder and subfolders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows you can do `for /R %i in (*.jar) do call_jar_signer.cmd %i` in command line.
Jar signing tool is in jdk\Bin folder

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Ant [SignJar](http://www.jajakarta.org/ant/ant-1.6.1/docs/en/manual/Tasks/signjar.html) task